# Calling a method in another activity from an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I know that we can't call a method from an Activity that's in another Activity. I'm trying to figure out the best way around this.

Here is my code. This is the method I am trying to call. It is in my `ScoreCard` activity.

```
public void numPlayerSetup(){
{
    int[] ids = {
        R.id.TextView11, R.id.TextView12, R.id.TextView13
    };

    for(int i : ids) {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(i);
        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Here is how I am trying to call the method. `score` is an object of the `ScoreCard` class.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
    int item = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();


    if(item==1){
        Log.i("error","This Sucks");
        score.numPlayerSetup();
    }
}
```

I tried to put the `numPlayerSetup` method in a different class that would not extend `Activity`, just contain the logic, but I can't use the `findViewById()` method without extending activity.

This is how I am calling it.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
    int item = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
    ArrayList<TextView> myTextViewList = new ArrayList<TextView>();

    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView14);
    myTextViewList.add(tv1);

    if(item==1){
        Log.i("error","This Sucks");
        Setup.numPlayerSetup(myTextViewList);
    }
```

Then this is the class I am calling.

```
public class Setup {
    TextView tv;

    public static void numPlayerSetup(ArrayList<TextView> tvs){
        for(TextView tv : tvs) {
            Log.i("crash","This Sucks");
            tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  //this line is highlighted in the debugger as the line my error is coming from
        }    
    }
}
```

It logs the message in the logcat and gives me a null pointer exception. The debugger says that the value for tv is null. Is this why I am getting a null pointer exception?

Comment: remove instance variable TextView tv

Answer (score 5):

You can just make a Utitlity class(not Activity) and pass in the Textviews you wish to change. and call that method whenever you need it.

```
public class Setup {

public static void numPlayerSetup(ArrayList<TextView> tvs){

                 for(TextView tv : tvs) {
                            tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }    
             }
}
```

Then you can use it like(in Activity):

```
ArrayList<TextView> myTextViewList = new ArrayList<TextView>();
TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
myTextViewList.add(tv1);


    Setup.numPlayerSetup(myTextViewList);
```

Comment: I love this idea, but I am getting a null pointer exception. I didn't realize I couldn't add code in the comments so I'll add it above.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that extends Activity

```
public class ScoreCard extends Activity{ 
 // ...   
public void numPlayerSetup(){  
        {  
             int[] ids = {  
                        R.id.TextView11, R.id.TextView12, R.id.TextView13
                    };

                    for(int i : ids) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(i);
                        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                 }
             }
}
```

Now if you want to create an Activity and you want to call the method just extend `ScoreCard`

```
public class AnotherActivity extends ScoreCard{  
  // ...  

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
        int item = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();


        if(item==1){
            Log.i("success","This Rocks");
            numPlayerSetup();

    }
    }
```

}

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Ok well the activity I am calling it from is already extending MapActivity.  I tried to create a class that extended ScoreCard and calling that class and having it call the method but that force closed. Null pointer exception. Sorry if thats not very clear.  I can add some code it its needed.

Comment: So... ScoreCard extends Activity (or MapActivity) and MainActivity extends ScoreCard. The point here is that you reuse the code from ScoreCard in MainActivity (just like you do in Java) and you extend Activity so you can display something on the screen in the same time. Post some lines from the Logcat so we can why if the NullPointerException thrown

Comment: sorry I wasn't very clear.  MainActivity extends MapActivity.  ScoreCard extends Activity.  I have an onClick listener in MainActivity that when it is clicked calls a method from ScoreCard.  I can't do: MainActivity extends ScoreCard because MainActivity is already extending MapActivity.

Answer (score 0):

calling an activity from another activity

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Textview 4"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Textview 1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
    android:text="Textview 2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="textview 3"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView14"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10" />
```

**main1.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is screen 2 called from activity scorecard."/>



</RelativeLayout>>
```

**ScoreCard.java**

```
package com.example.score.card;


public class ScoreCard extends Activity {

TextView textview1, textview2, textview3;
EditText editText1, editText2, editText3;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    onItemSelected();
}

private void onItemSelected() {
     textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
     textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
     textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
     editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
     setOnclickListener(textview1);
     setOnclickListener(textview2);
     setOnclickListener(textview3);     
}

private void setOnclickListener(final TextView textview12) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textview12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // textview12+" is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScoreCard2.class);
            intent.putExtra("editText1", editText1.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("editText2", editText2.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("editText3", editText3.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

**ScoreCard2.java**

```
package com.example.score.card;


public class ScoreCard2 extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    onItemSelected();
}

 private void onItemSelected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
         String strText1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("editText1");
         String strText2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("editText2");
         String strText3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("editText3");
         setOnclickListener(strText1);
         setOnclickListener(strText2);
         setOnclickListener(strText3);      
    }
private void setOnclickListener(String textview12) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
     textview12+" is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.score.card"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ScoreCard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_score_card" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <activity android:name=".ScoreCard2"></activity>
</application>
```